# Binding id to each layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup

`bindPopup` gives the correct id, how do I get the correct id from the click event?

The code below gives the id of the last layer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>question</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;"></div>   
</body>
</html>
<script>
var latArAr = [[55,55],[55.2,55.2],[55.4,55.4]];
var lngArAr = [[-1,-3],[-1,-3],[-1,-3]];
var idAr = [0,1,2];
var colAr = ["#FF0000","#FF8000","#FFFF00"];
const map = L.map('map',{
  doubleClickZoom: false, 
  zoomControl: false,
  center: [55.60418, -1.62987],
  zoom: 7       
});
new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);
const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var boundsAr = [];
var myLinesAr = [];
for (i = 0; i <latArAr.length;i++) {
  var latAr = latArAr[i];
  var lngAr = lngArAr[i];
  var id = idAr[i];
  var pipAr = [];
  for (j = 0; j <latAr.length;j++) {            
    if(latAr[j]){
      var pip = [];
      var lng = Number(lngAr[j]);
      var lat = Number(latAr[j]);
      pip.push(lng);
      pip.push(lat);
      pipAr.push(pip);
      var newLatLng = new L.latLng(Number(latAr[j]), Number(lngAr[j]));
      boundsAr.push(newLatLng);
    } 
  }
  var myLines = [{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": pipAr
  }];
  myLinesAr.push(myLines);
  L.geoJSON(myLines, {
    style: function (feature) {
      return {
        stroke: true,
        color: colAr[i], 
        id: idAr[i],
        weight: 15};
       },
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer, e) {                              
      layer.bindPopup(id+")  id is correct");       //id is correct
      layer.on('click', function(){
        console.log("id = "+id)                     //gives id of last element
        //window.open('x.php?id='+id);
      });
    }
  }).addTo(map);
}

var bounds = new L.bounds;
var polyline = new L.Polyline(boundsAr);
bounds = (polyline.getBounds());
map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: [1, 1] });
</script>
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On way to bind id to each GeoJSON layer is to use `onEachFeature` option function, by adding to the layer some property that does no interfere with standard Leaflet layer properties.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
  layer.myId = id;
  layer.bindPopup(id + ")  id is correct");
  layer.on('click', function(evt){
    console.log('Clicked id: ' + evt.target.myId);
  });
}
```

Comment: That works great, many thanks